# Android TabHost Center active Tab

Tags: android, center, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-tabs

Is it possible to change Android Tabs that if you press one, it comes to the center of the TabHost. Only 3 Tabs are visible, doesn't matter how many there are. Like in the Android 4.0 Google Music App!
If it is, how would you do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did find the answer myself.
If somebody else needs it, this should do it:

```
    final HorizontalScrollView mHorizontalScrollView;
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final double tabWidth = (int) (150 * scale + 0.5f);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = (int) tabWidth;
    }

    final double screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getWidth();
    mHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hscrollview);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int nrOfShownCompleteTabs = ((int) (Math.floor(screenWidth
                    / tabWidth) - 1) / 2) * 2;
            int remainingSpace = (int) ((screenWidth - tabWidth - (tabWidth * nrOfShownCompleteTabs)) / 2);

            int a = (int) (tabHost.getCurrentTab() * tabWidth);
            int b = (int) ((int) (nrOfShownCompleteTabs / 2) * tabWidth);
            int offset = (a - b) - remainingSpace;

            mHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(offset, 0);
        }
    });
```