# How to center SlidingTabStrip like in Play Market?

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm using `https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java` tabs class.

After applying it to my project, I get (no centered) tabs as shown by 
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYaAK.jpg), but i want to **center** my tabs like on [Play Market](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXeRE.jpg) tabs.

How do I center my tabs like in the Google Play app, Thanks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TabHost Center active Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878785/android-tabhost-center-active-tab)

Comment: @karaokyo its quite obvious that its not a duplicate :D

Comment: @AndreyLaw Could you show the code you used? All i could do now is to give you a link to a good tutorial - http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

Comment: Same code, like on you link. I think - need change SlidingTabLayout.java for centering support. How do that ? Maybe someone do it )

Comment: @edwinj it's conceptually very similar

Comment: The default (deprecated) action bar tabs that you can get via `New Project > Tabbed Activity > Action Bar Tabs` already exhibits your desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `scrollToTab` method to center the selected tab.

```
private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int tabWidth = selectedChild.getWidth();
        int tabPosition = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;
        int targetScrollX = tabPosition - viewWidth / 2 + tabWidth / 2;

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  but little no smoothly. After tab getting the center position, tab little slide to the left (or to right).  
[Check video](http://tinypic.com/r/sy4as7/8)

Comment: Are you telling me that it wasn't doing that before you made the change? This seems to be a problem with the animation logic, which I didn't touch nor look at as it has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: You not right - animation before you changes be good. I now use this library 
https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip
See screen: all ok :) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/master/art/material_tabs.gif
Animation, centering - all OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your **activity_main.xml** file should like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I dont know anything else that could have gone wrong.

[image]

Comment: I think you totally not understand me, and you have only 2 tabs , HOW 2 TABS CAN CENTER ON SCREEN. Here my string array <string-array name="tabs">
        <item>Категории</item>
        <item>Главная</item>
        <item>Топ платных</item>
        <item>Топ платных</item>
        <item>Топ бесплатных</item>
        <item>Бестселлеры</item>
        <item>Топ новых платных</item>
        <item>Топ новых бесплатных</item>
        <item>Набирающие популярность</item>

    </string-array>

Comment: Create all tabs from string array , and try to center tabs like i show on the SCREEN AND ON THE VIDEO... Your layout nothing's matter to my problem... Layout is good, SlidingTabLayout.java - NOT GOOD . You have only 2 tabs - create more tabs

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little bit of time on this and recently got it working. Here's the summary.

**SlidingTabLayout.java**
You must modify the `scrollToTab` method to compute the correct scroll. I've added explanatory comments here:

```
private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, float positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    View nextChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex + 1);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        // c1 is the center of the currently selected tab
        int c1 = selectedChild.getLeft() + (selectedChild.getWidth() / 2);

        // viewCenter is the center of the parent view
        int viewCenter = getWidth() / 2;

        int targetCenter = c1;
        if (nextChild != null) {
            // c2 is the center of the tab to the right of the currently selected
            int c2 = nextChild.getLeft() + (nextChild.getWidth() / 2);

            // the 'targetCenter' is partway between c1 & c2 depending on how far the viewpager
            // is currently scrolled
            targetCenter = (int) (c1 + ((c2 - c1) * positionOffset));
        }

        int targetScrollX = targetCenter - viewCenter;

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}
```

Note that this has changed the argument `positionOffset` from an `int` to a `float`, this is intentional as we can no longer use the original value passed in from the `InternalViewPagerListener`'s `onPageScrolled` method as it did not take into account the next tab's width. This means that in that `onPageScrolled` method we must change:

```
        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);
```

to be:

```
        scrollToTab(position, positionOffset);
```

This gives us access to the raw `positionOffset` param that we need to do the correct computation.

These are the only modifications needed. I've posted a gist of the full class here: https://gist.github.com/danh32/c39465c8b04db059fe72